# How to put side two select results in columns side by side?

Tags: sql

everyone! I have a query that calculates an average of a certain KPI on a period of time and groups it by the asset name. However, I have ten indicators for each asset and would like to show the query result side by side like this:

```
ASSET         Ind_X01   Ind_X02   Ind_X03  ...  Ind_X10
Asset01         10         25       21%    ...    46 
Asset02         15         15       25%    ...    10
Asset03         84         08       73%    ...    00
...
Asset_N         74         89       50%    ...    87
```

I made a query which does that for each ASSET's indicator, but I couldn't find a way to concatenate them together, side by side as shown above. I only got independent queries, each one with one column:

Query 01 to read indicator 01:

```
ASSET         Ind_X01  
Asset01         10       
Asset02         15     
Asset03         84     
...
Asset_N         74
```

Query 02 to read indicator 02:

```
ASSET         Ind_X01  
Asset01         10       
Asset02         15     
Asset03         84     
...
Asset_N         74
```

and so on...

The query I'm using is the one below, and by changing the IndicatorName I can run for the others:

```
local IndicatorName char(3);

IndicatorName = 'X01';

MACRO ColumnTitle = 'Ind_'||IndicatorName;

select ASSETS, avg(IND_CALCS) as &ColumnTitle from DB
where 
    DB_KPI_NAME = IndicatorName and
    DB_DATETIME between cast('2020-08-08 19:00:00.0' as timestamp format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.T') and cast('2020-08-10 23:59:59.0' as timestamp format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.T')
group by ASSETS
```

Could you guys help me with this? Thanks.

Comment: [Why should I tag my DBMS](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/388759/)

Comment: Use `case` expressions to do _conditional aggregation_.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you want something like this:

```
select ASSETS,
       avg(case when indicatorname = 'X01' then IND_CALCS end) as ind_X01,
       avg(case when indicatorname = 'X02' then IND_CALCS end) as ind_X02,
       avg(case when indicatorname = 'X03' then IND_CALCS end) as ind_X03,
       . . . 
from DB
where DB_DATETIME between cast('2020-08-08 19:00:00.0' as timestamp format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.T') and cast('2020-08-10 23:59:59.0' as timestamp format 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS.T')
group by ASSETS;
```